# How to execute a make target on file change automatically?

Tags: go, makefile

How do I write a `make` target that will watch for any file changes in specific folders and execute some other make target to compile files? I am looking for a way that can do this with minimal dependency on tools in addition to `make` itself to keep things simple.

Comment: You cannot do this (under the constraint minimal dependency).

Comment: @Volker, can you please suggest  just a way to do this with make using external tools?

Comment: You need some tool watching the file system and call make. These fs-watching tools are typically OS dependent. So look for files system watching tool which suites your need. (This has nothing to do with make).

Comment: It is make's purpose to update what needs to be upon file changes. So, if *watch*, in your question, means *take into account*, just write a makefile with the proper rules (target, prerequisites, recipe) and call make to do the job. If *watch* means *periodically check and update if needed*, then it is not a make question, it is a question about periodically executing a task, whatever it is and does. Under MAC OS X, GNU/Linux or UNIX systems, have a look at `cron` and `anacron`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

For the watching you can use [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch). (There's also a go version of this program which may be easier to install: [fswatch](https://github.com/codeskyblue/fswatch)) For example:

```
fswatch -ext cpp,c,h make -f Makefile
```

Anytime you change a `cpp`, `c` or `h` file it will run make again.

Make can be a bit slow for this, so I tend to use [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html) instead, but that really depends on the size of your project.

Another option is [tup](http://gittup.org/tup/), which has watching built-in:

```
tup monitor
```

But, sadly, only for linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**entr**](https://github.com/eradman/entr) and adjust your `Makefile` similar to this one

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := run
SHELL := /bin/bash

run:
    clear && \                    
    cp one.txt two.txt && \       
    rm -f _* *.l2m *.o2m && \     
    Ganlib < testgan2.x2m

watch:
    while sleep 1 ; do find . -name '*.x2m' -o -name '*.c2m' \
    | entr -d make -f ./Makefile ; done

.PHONY: run watch
```

followed by

```
$ make watch
```